# How to replace arguments.callee to be able to 'use strict'

Tags: javascript

I have some old code and I need to refactor/rewrite **arguments.callee.caller.caller** and **arguments.callee.caller** in two funcs to be able to 'use strict'.
Can be max up to ECMAScript 2019, thanks!

```
const utils = {
/**
 * @return {string}
 */
caller: function (string, callerName) {
    const caller = /^function\s+([^(]+)/.exec(/** @type{string} */ arguments.callee.caller.caller.toString());
    return caller ? caller[1] : '';
},
/**
 * @return {string}
 */
function_name: function () {
    const caller = /^function\s+([^(]+)/.exec(/** @type{string} */ arguments.callee.caller.toString());
    return caller ? caller[1] : '';
}
```

};

Comment: Warning: The 5th edition of ECMAScript (ES5) forbids use of arguments.callee() in strict mode.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee

Comment: AFAIK there is no strict mode safe way to get information about the caller.

Comment: Simply pass in the function (name) explicitly where it is really needed. Get rid of this `utils` object.

Comment: @Bergi, I can't do that because utils is linked with 100 other funcs, example:

```
function on_char(code) {
 console.log(utils.function_name());
}

function buttonEventHandler(x, y, m) {
 const c = utils.caller();
}
```

Comment: @German_Detlev yes you can, or rather, yes you will need to. Write `console.log("on_char")` and `function buttonEventHandler(x, y, m, c = "") {…}` instead. If it's only a hundred occurrences, you can quickly do this by hand, if it's more, an automated codemod might help you. There's no way around modernising your code.